# Awk - replace one character only in a certain column

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have a file like this:

```
2018.01.02;1.5;comment 1
2018.01.04;2.75;comment 2
2018.01.07;5.25;comment 4
2018.01.09;1.25;comment 7
```

I want to replace all dots `.` in the second column with a comma `,` as I would with `sed 's/\./\,/g' file` how can I use `sed` or preferably `awk` to only apply this for the second column, so my output would look like this:

```
2018.01.02;1,5;comment 1
2018.01.04;2,75;comment 2
2018.01.07;5,25;comment 4
2018.01.09;1,25;comment 7
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} {gsub(/\./, ",", $2)} 1' ip.txt
2018.01.02;1,5;comment 1
2018.01.04;2,75;comment 2
2018.01.07;5,25;comment 4
2018.01.09;1,25;comment 7
```

- `BEGIN{}` this block of code will be executed before processing any input line
- `FS=OFS=";"` set input and output field separator as `;`
- `gsub(/\./, ",", $2)` for each input line, replace all the `.` in 2nd field with `,`
- `1` is an awk idiom to print contents of `$0` (which contains the input record)

Answer (score 13):

```
sed 's/\./,/3' file
```

replace the third occurence of the dot

Answer (score 11):

Done by below method using awk

Command: `awk -F ";" '{gsub(/\./,",",$2);print $1";"$2";"$3}' filename`

output

```
2018.01.02;1,5;comment 1
2018.01.04;2,75;comment 2
2018.01.07;5,25;comment 4
2018.01.09;1,25;comment 7
```